# Curl To Pycurl Translation

Tags: pycurl

I have been working with curl request (from bash)

/usr/bin/curl -L -k  -u admin:admin -X GET 'https://localhost/test/123/123'

**How can I translate this request to the pycurl code, and implement it through python, options are important as it is REST API.**

The options that I used in curl are

-k for insecure(ssl bypass)

-L  redirect

-X request GET

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is [documentation](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlobject.html#curlobject) that you can read for information. It references [CURL's setopt options](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html). If you read the documentation you'd figure out what you want to know, but I assume you're asking here because you want someone else to read it for you.

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, "https://localhost/test/123/123")
c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False) # -k
c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True) # -L
c.setopt(c.HTTPGET, True) # -X
c.perform()
```